# ResNet: ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_7

Tags: python, keras, classification, resnet

I have trained my ResNet101V2 model (keras) and have saved the model. On loading the model and trying to classify a new image, I keep getting the error: `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_7: expected shape=(None, 255, 255, 3), found shape=(None, 255, 3)`

Here's my code:

```
load_path = 'path to my model'
model = keras.models.load_model(load_path)

image_path = 'path to my image'
img_np = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
resized_img_np = cv2.resize(img_np, (255, 255))
print(resized_img_np.shape) # <============= PRINTS (255, 255, 3)

prediction = model.predict(resized_img_np) # <========= ERROR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an extra dimension `to match with batch size`. Add a dimension using [np.expand_dims](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) to the resized image and pass to model for predictionion.

```
resized_img_np = np.expand_dims(resized_img_np,axis=0)
prediction = model.predict(resized_img_np)
```

Answer (score 2):

As the model was trained on batches you have to add a batch value of 1 for a single sample,
the error indicated that the size should be:

```
(None, 255, 255, 3)
```

Where the `None` shows the varying batchsize.

You can simply solve this by adding a "1" as the first dimension of your input image, showing that you are going to classify only one image.

Where the shape instead of `(255, 255, 3)` would be:

```py
import numpy as np

resized_img_np = cv2.resize(np.array(img_np), (255, 255))
resized_img_np = np.expand_dims(resized_img_np, axis=0)
```